# Is $(X^3 - 18X + 12, 5) \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ a prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I'm trying to determine wheter $A = (X^3 - 18X + 12, 5)$ and $B = (X^3 - 18X + 12, X-1)$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. I know that $A = \mathbb{Q}[X]$ since I can make $\frac{1}{5}\cdot 5 = 1$, so it is not a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. But with the other options, I'm stuck. I know that $X^3 -18X + 12$ is irreducible in both $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ and $\mathbb{Q}[X]$. I've tried to show that $A$ and $B$ are maximal ideals, by using the first isomorphism theorem. If $f$ is the natural map $\mathbb{Z}[X] \to \mathbb{Z}[X]/A$ (with kernel $A$), then $\mathbb{Z}[X]/A$ is isomorphic to $f[\mathbb{Z}[X]]$. But at this point I'm stuck, as I don't know what the image of $f$ is.

Comment: Try to prove these general theorems: (1) $R/(r_1,r_2) \cong [R/(r_1)]/(\overline{r_2})$, where $\overline{r_2}$ is the image of $r_2$ in $R/(r_1)$; and (2) if $r \in R$, then $R[X]/(r) \cong (R/(r))[X]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* (1). $\mathbb Z[X]/A \cong \dfrac{\mathbb Z[X]/(5)}{A/(5)} \cong \mathbb Z_5[X]/(X^3 - 3X + 2)$ and $(X^3 - 3X + 2)$ is reducible in $\mathbb Z_5$ as it has a root in $\mathbb Z_5.$

(2). $\mathbb Z[X]/B \cong \dfrac{\mathbb Z[X]/(X-1)}{B/(X-1)} \cong \mathbb Z_5.$

Comment: Do you mean $\mathbb{Z}[X]/A \cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^3 -3X + 2)$?

Comment: No. That's not true. I've edited it. See if you have any question.

Comment: Why is $\frac{(\mathbb{Z}[X]/(X-1)}{B/(X-1)}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5$?

Comment: $\mathbb Z[X]/(X-1) \cong \mathbb Z,$ and to determine $B/(X-1),$ simply divide $X^3 - 18X + 12$ by $X-1.$ The remainder term is $-5$ (assuming my calculation is correct).

Comment: And since $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is a field, $B$ is a maximal ideal and therefore prime?

Comment: Yes! $B$ is a maximal ideal and hence a prime ideal also. But $A$ is not as the polynomial $X^3 -3X +2$ is not irreducible.